Adding elements into a char array
I've been trying to make a function in C that takes a string as the input and then prints out a version of that string that only contains alpha characters.
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char isAlpha(char charArr[]){
    int i, j, stringLen, alphaLen;
    stringLen = strlen(charArr);
    char alphaArr[30];

    for(i= 0; i < stringLen; i++){
        if(isalpha(charArr[i]) != 0){
            strcat(alphaArr, charArr[i]);
        }
    }
    alphaLen = strlen(alphaArr);
    for(j = 0; j <  alphaLen; j++){
        printf("%c", alphaArr[j]);
    }
}

I've tried using the strcat() function to add the non-alpha characters in a new variable, but nothing prints out once I run it in my main function.

Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates what you observe.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. In addition to what's suggested in Vlad from Moscow's answer, a couple of things you can do to allow your code to work for up to 29 characters are to first add something like alphaArr[0] = '\0'; after the declaration of alphaArr, to initialize it to a proper NULL-terminated string. Next, such as explained in C library - strncat() function, since strcat is for concatenating a NULL-terminated string, replace it with strncat(alphaArr, &charArr[i], 1);.

Using strcat() leads to quadratic behaviour (assuming you end up initializing alphaArr appropriately).  The first call skips 0 characters before adding the new one; the second skips 1; the third 2; the fourth 3; the Nth skips N-1.  But with the previous skips, you've skipped N(N-1)/2 characters, which is quadratic behaviour.  It may not matter for strings as short as 29 characters; it would matter for strings measured in kilobytes.

(1.) As in @vlad-from-moscow 's answer, you should initialize the alphaArr buffer before using it. Learn the concept of null-terminating string in C. (2.) strcat concatenates two strings, not one string and a character, so you wrongly used the function here. The right way is alphaArr[alphaLen] = charArr[i].

@JonathanLeffler you could do something like strcat(alphaArr + i, ...) to avoid quadratic complexity but that's just a silly complication, since there are better solutions for the root issue.

@JohnOmielan Using alphaArr[alphaLen] = charArr[i] is faster than strncat(alphaArr, &charArr[i], 1). You just concatenate one character, and thus strncat is not needed at all.

If your compiler doesn't shout at you for strcat(alphaArr, charArr[i]); due to passing incorrect argument type, then you need to crank up diagnostics level. For gcc or clang use -Wall -Wextra -pedantic.

This declaration with the magic number 30
char alphaArr[30];

declares an uninitialized character array.That is its content is indetermined.
The function strcat is declared the following way
char *strcat(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2);

It expects two pointers to strings. So this call
strcat(alphaArr, charArr[i])

is invalid even if to ignore that the first argument points to an array with an indeterminate content (the first argument must be a pointer to a string) at least because the second argument has the integer type char instead of a pointer to char.
In any case there is no great sense to use the function strcat to append one character to a character array. You could just use a separate index in the for loop for the destination array.
Moreover the function returns nothing though its return type is not void.
And the function should do only one thing: either it should build a new string or it should only output alpha characters of the passed string.
And as the passed string is not changed within the function the parameter should be declared with qualifier const.
Calling the function strlen in any case is redundant. And calling the function for a character array that does not contain a string results in undefined behavior.
To output only alpha characters of a string the function can be defined the following way
void isAlpha( const char charArr[] )
{
    for ( ; *charArr != '\0'; ++charArr )
    {
        if ( isalpha( ( unsigned char ) *charArr ) )
        {
            putchar( *charArr );
        }
    }
}

or the following way
FILE * isAlpha( const char charArr[], FILE *fp )
{
    for ( ; *charArr != '\0'; ++charArr )
    {
        if ( isalpha( ( unsigned char ) *charArr ) )
        {
            putc( *charArr, fp );
        }
    }

    return fp;
}

If you need to create a new array that contains a string of alpha characters of the source string then you need to allocate memory dynamically for the new character array that will contain a string and return a pointer to it from the function.

Minor note: that last version with putc might want to check that fp is not NULL.
